# How to set a checkbox value upon the click of a button in a different activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, checkbox

A checkbox is present in MainActivity,in another activity there is a button "Accept",upon button click the checkbox value is to be set in MainActivity.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click Listener

```
public interface NextClickListener {


    public void nextButtonClicked(int tag);
}
```

Activity Implement

```
MainActivity implements NextClickListener 

@Override
    public void nextButtonClicked(int tag) {
      //Do what you want to do here

    }
```

Please note down if it doesn't work and meet your needs